# Magento 2: The requested component ("int") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation

Tags: magento2

I am getting this following error while editing the product. This issue occurred after sync the products from Akeneo to Magento using Pimgento 2 API.

**Issue:** The requested component ("int") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

**Environment:**
Magento CE 2.1.9, Akeneo CE 2.3, PHP 7, Mysql 5.7.25

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Sync products from Akeneo to Magento using Pimgento 2 API
2. After sync try to edit products, it throws an error

**Expected results**

1. I should be able to edit the product in admin grid.

**Actual results**

The requested component ("int") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

Comment: I have fixed it by updating the frontend_input field in eav_attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: select attribute_id from eav_attribute where frontend_input='int'

Step2: update eav_attribute set frontend_input='text' where attribute_id in (your_attribute_ids_from_step1)

Step3: If Step 2 solves your problem. Find out the exact attribute & update the same